# Embedding TTF Font @Font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, embed, truetype

Been trying for a while, I've done

```
<style> 
@font-family {
 font-family: 'bebas';
 src: url( monthly.square7.ch/bebas/bebas.ttf; } 

span {
font-family: bebas ;
}
</style>
<span> hello </span>
```

---

```
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: bebas;
src: url(monthly.bplaced.net/bebas/bebas.ttf);
}
</style>

<div style="font-family: bebas;">
Bebas font test
</div>
```

and inline which apparently wont work

--- The font is located at http://monthly.square7.net/bebas/bebas.ttf

I also asked earlier but had no luck.
[Does anyone know how to embed ttf fonts in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608884/does-anyone-know-how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-in-website/28608967?noredirect=1#comment45523413_28608967)

Comment: Are those URLs meant to represent folders? If they're meant to represent URLs, you need to prefix with `http://`.

Comment: even wih http:// it doesnt work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does anyone know how to embed ttf fonts in website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608884/does-anyone-know-how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-in-website)

Comment: i mentioned that at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the information from [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608884/does-anyone-know-how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-in-website), and that your CSS is on `monthly.co.vu`, you're running into [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problems.

You will likely have the following error in your browser console:

> Redirect at origin 'http://monthly.square7.ch' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://monthly.co.vu' is therefore not allowed access.

Your font is being served from a different domain than your page, so you'll need to serve the following header with your TTF:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: monthly.co.vu
```

Then your font can be embedded in the page.

Alternatively, you should simply host the font on the same domain as the page you're accessing, and avoid these problems.

Comment: paste in header right?

do i do it as: <acces-control-allow-origin: monthly.co.vu>

Comment: No, HTTP headers are served by your Web server (e.g. Apache/nginx). You might be able to add it to a `.htaccess` file if it's Apache.

Comment: i dont understand?? i know apache and nginx are supposedely like server operating systems

Comment: Sounds like you need to read about how Web servers work. Why are your using more than one domain? Maybe that would be the easier fix for you.

Comment: i have a hosting account on one domain, but i like the other domain better

Comment: im just a young boy inspired by technological prodigies who turn into billionares

Answer (score 0):

You have some code problems, try this:

```css
@font-face{ 
  font-family: 'bebas';
  src: url('http://monthly.square7.ch/bebas/bebas.ttf');
    
}


span {
     font-family: 'bebas', Arial, sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<span> hello </span>
```

Comment: @Tobi , it works on chrome. There are some issues on the firefox.Try adding more fallback (bebas.eot)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an alternative method using **Data URIs** which should most definitely work since you wont be dealing with cross domain requests (if that was the issue earlier). Just be aware that you will be sending more data on each page reload if the data is not cashed.

Convert the font into a data string [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and paste it directly into @font-face. See [this post](http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri) for more details

```
src: url('data:font/ttf;base64,"DATA STRING GOES HERE WITHOUT QUOTES"')
```